# ObjectMapper in spring boot can read string, but doesn't work when parsing headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am trying to give an enum value as a header parameter to my rest endpoint in a spring boot `@RestController`. To that end I put the jackson libraries in my `build.gradle` file since the autogenerated enum used jackson annotations. I cannot change the enum code (it is autogenerated from a openapi specification). It looks like this:

```
public enum DocumentTypes {

  APPLICATION_PDF("application/pdf"),

  APPLICATION_RTF("application/rtf"),

  APPLICATION_VND_OASIS_OPENDOCUMENT_TEXT("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"),

  APPLICATION_VND_OPENXMLFORMATS_OFFICEDOCUMENT_WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"),

  APPLICATION_VND_MS_WORD("application/vnd.ms-word"),

  TEXT_HTML("text/html"),

  TEXT_PLAIN("text/plain");

  private String value;

  DocumentTypes(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  @JsonValue
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static DocumentTypes fromValue(String text) {
    for (DocumentTypes b : DocumentTypes.values()) {
      if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + text + "'");
  }
}
```

The restcontroller I am using to test looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(@RequestHeader(value = "Accept", required = false) DocumentTypes targetFormat) throws IOException {
        DocumentTypes value = objectMapper.readValue("\"application/pdf\"", DocumentTypes.class);
    }

}
```

If I don't supply the Accept header and just let break inside the code I can see that the first line of the code works fine, the `application/pdf` String is transformed into `value` so the `ObjectMapper` did its job using the `@JsonCreator` method.

However if I pass `Accept=application/pdf` header along with the request I get an error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'de.some.namespace.model.DocumentTypes'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader de.some.namespace.model.DocumentTypes] for value 'application/pdf'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant de.some.namespace.model.DocumentTypes.application/pdf"
```

This looks to me as if spring is not using the Jackson provided `ObjectMapper`, thus ignoring the `@JsonCreator` method and just trying to resolve the enum by default by looking if there is a key with that provided name.

This to me does not make sense, becuase I also only `@Autowire` the `ObjectMapper`,... isn't that the one that spring should also use, how can I force spring to use the correct one for parsing the arguments? I tried putting it into a `@Configuration` and making it a `@Bean` and `@Primary` with the same results.

I have a workaround by implementing a converter:

```
@Component
public class StringToDocumentTypesConverter implements Converter<String, DocumentTypes> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public DocumentTypes convert(String s) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(String.format("\"%s\"", s), DocumentTypes.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why this would be necessary, normally spring automatically puts arguments through the `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is working as designed. Spring only uses the Jackson `ObjectMapper` for conversion of message bodies (using a registered `HttpMessageConverter`, specifically the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`).

This is documented at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion:

> Some annotated controller method arguments that represent String-based request input (such as `@RequestParam`, `@RequestHeader`, `@PathVariable`, `@MatrixVariable`, and `@CookieValue`) can require type conversion if the argument is declared as something other than String.
>
> For such cases, type conversion is automatically applied based on the configured converters

And https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody:

> You can use the `@RequestBody` annotation to have the request body read and deserialized into an Object through an `HttpMessageConverter`

Comment: Thanks for the links to the documentation! It seems you are right. Only `@RequestBody` is automapped. At least the behaviour makes sense now, although I wished there was some way to tell Spring to use the object mapper as the default converter for `String -> T`, actually let's see if a templated `@Converter` works,...